# Need to create a custom data 2D texture with reasonable precision

Tags: c++, opengl

## The idea

I need to create a 2D texture to be fed with resonably precise float values (I mean at least as precise as a glsl `mediump float`). I want to store in it each pixel's distance from the camera. I *don't* want the GL Zbuffer distance to near plane, only my own lovely custom data :>

## The problem/What I've tried

- By using a standard texture as color attachment, I don't get enough precision. Or maybe I missed something ?
- By using a depth attachment texture as `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32` I am getting the clamped near plane distance - rubbish.

So it seems I am stuck at not using a depth attachment even tho they seem to eventually hold more precision. So is there a way to have `mediump float` precision for standard textures ?

I find it strange OpenGL doesn't have a generic container for arbitrary data. I mean with custom bit-depth. Or maybe I missed something again!

Comment: So you want to write custom data in the fragment shader? If this is the case you can use a floating point texture like a `GL_RGBA32F` or `GL_R32F` and store your data manually. If this is what you need i going to make a answer out of it.

Comment: Well yes, I pretty much need a data texture to store whatever I want in it (manually), with enough precision as the data will at least partially represent distances. My program is handling increasingly smaller distances (fractal geometry) hence the higher precision the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use floating point textures instead of a `RGBA` texture with 8 bit per pixel. However support of these depends on the devices you want to support, especially older mobile devices have a lack of support for these formats.

*Example for `GL_RGBA16F`( Not tested ):*

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mipmap, GL_RGBA16F, mipmapWidth, mipmapHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_HALF_FLOAT, null);
```

Now you can store the data in your fragment-shader manually. However clamping still occurs depending on you MVP. Also you need to pass the data to the fragment shader.

There are also 32bit formats.

Comment: I am targeting Windows/Unix/OSX desktops/laptops - no mobile devices. Would I run into any problems @ using `GL_RGBA32F` & `GL_FLOAT` ? I guess not ? What is a MVP ?

Comment: @PinkTurtle As long you are targeting OpenGL 3.0 and above you can be sure that they are supported: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Floating_point_and_mipmapping_and_filtering
`MVP == ModelViewProjection Matrix`

Comment: Fine. I'm not even yet at using MVPs. So far the only vertex geometry I am using is a quad to fill screen.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options for texture formats that give you more than 8-bit component precision.

If your values are in a pre-defined range, meaning that you can easily map your values into the [0.0, 1.0] interval, normalized 16-bit formats are your best option. For a single component texture, the format would be `GL_R16`. You can allocate a texture of this format using:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16, 512, 512, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
```

There are matching formats for 2, 3, and 4 components (`GL_RG16`, `GL_RGB16`, `GL_RGBA16`).

If you need a larger range of values that is not easily constrained, float textures become more attractive. The corresponding calls for 1 component textures are:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16F, 512, 512, 0, GL_RED, GL_HALF_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, 512, 512, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

Again, there are matching formats for 2, 3, and 4 components.

The advantage of float textures is that, just based on the nature of float values encoded with a mantissa and exponent, they can cover a wide range. This comes at the price of less precision. For example, `GL_R16F` gives you 11 bits of precision, while `GL_R16` gives you a full 16 bits. Of course `GL_R32F` gives you plenty of precision (24 bits) as well as a wide range, but it uses twice the amount of storage.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have an easier time accomplishing this in GLSL as opposed to the C API.  However, any custom depth buffer will be consistently, considerably slower than the one provided by OpenGL.  Don't expect it to operate in real-time.

If your aim is to have access to the raw distance of any fragment from the camera, remember that depth buffer values are z/w, where z is the distance from the near plane and w is the distance from the camera.  So, it is possible to extract quickly with an acceptable amount of precision.  However, you are still faced with your original problem: fragments between the camera and the near plane will not be in the depth buffer.

Comment: I need more a custom high precision texture than depth buffer. Actually I don't want to cope with recomputing values back from a depth buffer, I don't even know at this point what near/far planes represent and how to handle them. I *just only just* need a *place* to store my data that's easily accessible in read/write mode inside the fragment shader. I already implemented the GPU Ping-Pong technique for this purpose.

Comment: @PinkTurtle So, you just need a storage?  Computation of data is irrelevant for the question?  If so, [the OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture#Image_formats) has sufficient data on the topic.

Comment: I am already computing an estimation of the distance to the camera inside the fragment shader, so I need a texture to store that value. And read that value back at next frame.

Comment: Relevant link was relevant.  Accepted answer explains a single format capable of doing the job, wiki link provided several.